# Can I get a digital copy of the Journal of Halacha?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, technology

I was reading a *sefer* which cited the *Journal of Halacha and Contemporary Society #35*. Can I get a digital copy of this Journal?

Comment: Not likely as it's a paid journal. Some individual articles might be available online from the author, but I don't know about a whole journal.

Comment: What issue in particular?

Comment: If there is such a website, it is illegal as the work is under copyright.

Comment: You can subscribe at [their website](http://www.jlaw.com/About/jhcs.html). I'm under the impression that you can order back-issues of the journal, and possibly even digitally....try calling or emailing the Journal from the contact info on that page

Comment: @sam He says he wants #35, I dunno.....

Answer (score 1):

<sub><sup>Comment --> answer.</sup></sub>

You can subscribe from their [website](http://www.jlaw.com/About/jhcs.html). I'm under the impression that you can order back-issues of the journal, and possibly even digitally....try calling or emailing the Journal from the contact info on that page, LMK how that works out.